# Handle database insert conflict in ASP.NET Dynamic Data with ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, dynamic-data

I'm working on an ASP.NET Dynamic Data Entities project with Visual Studio 2013. My data source is an ADO.NET Entity Data Model based on a SQL Server database.

When I try to insert a new table entry that violates a unique key constraint I get a quite user-unfriendly error page with the whole stack trace.
Is it possible to just display a short error message in the Insert-view? (similar to the error message when a required field is left empty)

What I tried so far is to extend the following code in *Insert.aspx.cs*

```
protected void FormView1_ItemInserted(object sender, FormViewInsertedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Exception == null || e.ExceptionHandled) {
        Response.Redirect(table.ListActionPath);
    }
}
```

to this (checking on the unique key conflict with exception number 2627)

```
protected void FormView1_ItemInserted(object sender, FormViewInsertedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Exception == null || e.ExceptionHandled) {
        Response.Redirect(table.ListActionPath);
    }
    else
    {
        SqlException innerException = e.Exception.InnerException as SqlException;
        if (innerException != null)
        {
            if (innerException.Number == 2627)
            {
                // Violation of unique constraint
                throw new ValidationException("Unique key violation");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Although *Insert.aspx* uses an asp:DynamicValidator I get the the following exception:
**"ValidationException was unhandled by user code."**

Does anyone know what to do here? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Apparently there are some issues with ValidationExceptions in EF.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1476131.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2008/12/11/handling-database-exceptions-in-dynamic-data.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The `asp:DynamicValidator` must be bound to a specific control in order to work (using the `ControlToValidate` property): it will then intercept any exception (not just the `ValidationException`) occurring in that control's server-side events.

In your scenario i would use an `asp:CustomValidator` instead and act accordingly:

**ASP.NET Page:**

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" id="myValidationControl"
    OnServerValidate="myValidationControl_ServerValidate" />
```

**Code-behind:**

```
private bool _ConstraintViolation = false;

protected void FormView1_ItemInserted(object sender, FormViewInsertedEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.Exception == null || e.ExceptionHandled) {
        Response.Redirect(table.ListActionPath);
    }
    else
    {
        SqlException innerException = e.Exception.InnerException as SqlException;
        if (innerException != null)
        {
            if (innerException.Number == 2627)
            {
                // Violation of unique constraint
                _ConstraintViolation = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

void myValidationControl_ServerValidate (object source, ServerValidateEventArgs a)
{
    if (_ConstraintViolation)
    {
        a.IsValid = false;
        myValidationControl.ErrorMessage = 
        myValidationControl.Text = "Unique key violation";
    }
    else a.IsValid = true;
}
```

You'll need to adapt my code to your page (i.e. attaching the right `ValidationGroup`, etc.) but this should solve your issue.